# NSURL check if webpage or downloadable file

Tags: objective-c, web, download, nsurl, filesize

I download random URL's. Is there a way to find out if the URL is referring to a website or a downloadable file?

I currently use this:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

Setting a limit to the filesize of the website/file behind the URL is also an option.

Does anyone has any suggestions about how to find the difference between website or downloadable file and/or the size of the downloadable file?

Thnx!

Comment: The point is, some URL's could point to a file of 40MB for example. As far as my skills go I can only download the file first before I check for a <!doctype html>. Do you know any way of checking for the filesize?

Comment: you need to add that you want to do this without downloading the file to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `NSURLResponse` you can check `MIMEType` to check the file type and `expectedContentLength` to check the length and all that before starting to actually download it.

Comment: MimeType would be my suggestion too